# How to get new updated rows after performing update query in psql from JdbcTemplate in Spring boot

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, jdbc

I want to update limited set of rows and then get the updated rows. I need this to be an atomic call since multiple servers can perform the same request and I dont want to return duplicate values.

How do I do this?

I've tried this but it doesn't work.

```
    @Modifying
    @Transactional
    @Query(
        "update dto s set s.status=:status, s.agent_Id=:agentId where id in (select d.id from dto d where d.status=:pendingStatus limit 100)",
        nativeQuery = true
    )
    fun assignToAgentAndGetDtos(
        @Param("status") status: Int = 1
        @Param("agentId") agentId: String,
        @Param("pendingStatus") pendingStatus: Int = 0
    ): List<Dto>
```

`jdbcTemplate.update` only returns an `int`. I need updated rows instead.

Comment: That's not possible. You would have to execute a select to get the rows

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `RETURNING *` at the end.
More details: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/dml-returning.html